# Are there any records of a child born from Mages possessing strange quirks or mystical powers?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

To clarify. I am aware that being a Mage is not genetic and biologically speaking Mages are no different from humans(At least they aren't unless they modified their bodies. ) but Mages inflict their brand of magick on the world passively with the amount they are inflicting increasing along with their level of power. (Eventually reaching a degree where just staying in reality is a source of paradox) But does the resonance cause their kids to display traits related to the resonance whether it be in the form of turning them into a source of resonance themselves or giving them exceptional traits such as incredible creativity or being able to 'talk' to computers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It depends on your definition of born

The most strange mages are sometimes not the traditions, but the technocrats. Among them, biomodding, aka "organic enhancement" is a well-honored tradition, especially among the Progenitors. And among their lines... Well, let's say that beings created in their labs are not necessarily what you'd expect from what is written on their file as base material. And here comes in what I said in the header: It depends on what you define as born. So, let's look at different ways to use the word *born*:

- *Born naturally* from a mother?
- *Made that way* in a lab in a vat? Grown from tissue, maybe even opening their eyes the first time already enhanced with cybernetic implants?
- Taking in a healthy human and turning them into an entirely different being that is re-set, practically *reborn/remade*?
- Schooling and molding someone after birth through teaching and indoctrination into a *spiritual rebirth*?

##### File #[Redacted]: Common “Steelskin” Cyborg - *Reborn/Remade*

As described in M20, Appendix I: Allies and Antagonists, p.623, these are more or less *reborn* in a lab under Progenitor oversight. They are conditioned, trained, and have a fragment of personality. But they also most likely have a totally different body structure, so you wouldn't recognize Peter, the clerk from your local bank, after he has been turned into Project 1234.

##### File #[Redacted]: Bioenhanced Field Agent - *Reborn/Remade*

As described in M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter One: Sleepers, Consors, Hunters, and Night-Folk, p.51, Progenitors run bio-enhancement schemes on their field agents even in a limited fashion. The products of these projects are very akin to Captain America or other superheroes that acquired their powers after birth.

##### File #[Redacted]: Enlightened Shock Corps & Atlas Units - *Reborn/Remade*

As described in M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter Two: Constructs and Familiars, p.82, the goal of the Atlas Units was to turn Traditionalists into cybernetically enhanced helpers for the Technocracy. It had *some* success, but the project went... haywire. It's discontinued and some of the results became HIT Marks.

##### File #[Redacted]: HIT Mark - *Reborn/Remade or made that way*

As described in M20, Appendix I: Allies and Antagonists, p.624, Iteration X is one of the best customers when it comes to HIT Marks. M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter Two: Constructs and Familiars, p.82 there are many many models of them. These cybernetically and genetically modified humanoids (some have been *Mages* before subjection to this) might or might not use stock from Progenitor labs, making it possibly hard to place them on the categories of *born*.

##### File #[Redacted]: Project Victor - *made that way*

As described in M20, Appendix I: Allies and Antagonists, p.624, Project Victor, or *Homo superior* is the pinnacle of Bodymodification and genetic engineering. They are of the *grown in a lab* type, so are best considered *born that way*, though they do get *augmented* after birth and during training.

##### File #[Redacted]: Igors - *Born or reborn/remade?*

As described in M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter One: Sleepers, Consors, Hunters, and Night-Folk, p.41, Igors are a time-honored tradition among the Traditions to take on *helpers*, that are *different*. Some of these are offspring of a whole lineage of such Igors, making it hard to distinguish if they are modified after birth or if their predisposition is an inheritable trait that was given to them generations ago.

##### File #[Redacted]: Robots & artificial beings - *made that way*

As described in M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter Two: Constructs and Familiars, p.78, Some mages go the extra mile to create their own offspring from scratch. They are *different*. Like Darius, the Hologram adult toy. Or Masako 01, a doll-child made by an Etherist.

##### File #[Redacted]: Reanimates - *Reborn/Remade or Made that way*

As described in M20 Gods & Monsters, Chapter Two: Constructs and Familiars, p.85, some mages use dead to create beings that are no longer dead. Some of them are plain out *reanimation*, others are body horrors, such as Eye Scream. But Frankenstein's creation *also* counts and is even described in detail, and he was aimed to be the perfect companion by Doctor Frankenstein! Can you say those are anything but the *children* of their creators?

##### File #[Redacted]: Genetic Defects - *Born naturally*

As described in M20, Appendix II: Odd Ends, p.648, Genetic Flaws are a thing. Now, some mages, especially those that undergo a lot of bio-modding or mind sculpting, can result in giving their offspring the same or similar traits.

### Nature v Nurture

While all above is the (modified) nature of beings, a lot of traits are actually trained and learned. Nurture. Especially among the Hermetic Order, it was a long time common to have non-awakened offspring of mages be indoctrinated in Hedgemagic. This however is nurture and training. See also: M20 Sorcerer for this.